# Messed Up a Question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

I confused two ideas when asking a question, and I want to edit it to reflect what I actually meant. But two people already answered and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do that. Can I? I'd hate to spam a new question so soon.

Comment: Sorry to hear this, is this the question you refer to? [Artificial Gills: Electrolysis for gills?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/197466/artificial-gills-electrolysis-for-gills)

Comment: Nobody had answered your question until _after_ your edit (at which point I answered it). There's evidently been some confusion somewhere, but there's no obvious harm done.

Comment: For more information talk to your support https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8253/105737

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once a question gets answer(s) it is preferred that any edit doesn't invalidate them, out of respect for those who put effort in writing them and to avoid that a QA site turns out into a forum where edits keep chasing the answers.

---

And then, if the question you wrote and got answers to isn't really the question you actually wanted to ask, you can always (carefully!) ask a new question. The only caveat here is to make sure the new question that you had meant to ask is substantially different from the question you originally asked. Otherwise, your new question will be closed for being a duplicate.

Comment: I'll keep that in ind for future questions. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what the "carefully" does here. I'm sure you don't mean clandestinely.  If I were to do it I would start by linking to my old question and explaining the difference. What do you intend by "carefully"?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica, precisely that